# Rails asset pipeline retina @2x and cache buster timestamps are at odds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, retina-display, retina.js

retina.js looks for an image with the same filename but with @2x before the file extension

The rails asset pipeline adds a cache busting timestamp to the end of the filename

This means retina.js is looking for `filename-cachebuster@2x.png` but the file is at `filename@2x-cachebuster.png`

Anyone have a work around for this?

Who's wrong on this ie, should retina.js be trained to look for files at `filename@2x-cachebuster.png` if the original filename matches a pattern that indicates it has a cache busting hash, or should the rails pipeline be changed to ensure the @2x is always just before the file extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a bit of work around in and of itself but looks like the correct way to do this is:

```
<%= image_tag('image', retina: true) %>
```

and this will add the correct data-at2x attribute that retina.js will pick up

Comment: It's not adding that attribute for me - only add the `retina="true"`.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be a built-in Rails feature, I assume @msaspence is using [retina_rails](https://github.com/jhnvz/retina_rails). @justin-tanner’s answer below works if you are using [retina.js](http://retinajs.com).

Answer (score 5):

The `retina.js` documentation suggests using a rails helper method:

```
def image_tag_with_at2x(name_at_1x, options={})
  name_at_2x = name_at_1x.gsub(%r{\.\w+$}, '@2x\0')
  image_tag(name_at_1x, options.merge("data-at2x" => asset_path(name_at_2x)))
end
```

For more information check the **[retina.js documentation](https://github.com/imulus/retinajs#ruby-on-rails-3x)**.

Also make sure you have the latest version of **[retina.js](https://github.com/imulus/retinajs)**, supporting the `data-at2x` attribute.

Comment: This only works for images whose paths are defined in code or a view. See my answer for a way to solve it from CSS-land with a simple LESS mixin.

Answer (score 1):

For anything other than an image tag (i.e. CSS background images, which are much more widely used than `img` tags in most apps I've worked on), I've solved it by writing a little LESS helper which works like a charm.

```
.at2x(@path, @w: auto, @h: auto) {
  background-image: image-url(@path);
  @at2x_path: ~`"@{path}".replace(/(.*)\.([^.]+)$/, "$1@2x.$2")`;

  @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    background-image: image-url(@at2x_path);
    background-size: @w @h;
  }
}
```